# Java - String frequency with huge data

Tags: java, memory, substring

I am trying to find frequency of a longest substring in a huge string.

```
'Huge string' can be up to 2M characters long, only a-z
'Substring' may be between 100k to 2M characters long
'Substring' is always same or smaller size than 'Huge string'
```

currently, I am using following method which I created:

```
    public static int[] countSubstringOccurence(String input, int substringLength) {
      // input = from 100 000 to 2 000 000 alphanumeric characters long string;
      // substringLength = from 100 000 to 2 000 000, always smaller than input

      LinkedHashMap < String, Integer > substringOccurence = new LinkedHashMap < > ();
      int l;

      for (int i = 0; i < (input.length() - substringLength) + 1; i++) {
          String substring = input.substring(i, i + substringLength);
          if (substringOccurence.containsKey(substring)) {
              l = substringOccurence.get(substring);
              substringOccurence.put(substring, ++l);
          } else {
              substringOccurence.put(substring, 1);
          }
      }


      List < Integer > substringOccurenceList = new ArrayList < > (substringOccurence.values());
      int numberOfUniqueSubstrings = substringOccurenceList.size();
      int numberOfOccurenciesOfMostCommonSubstrings = 0;
      int numberOfSubstringsOfMostCommonSubstring = 0;

      for (int i: substringOccurenceList) {
          if (i > numberOfOccurenciesOfMostCommonSubstrings) {
              numberOfOccurenciesOfMostCommonSubstrings = i;
              numberOfSubstringsOfMostCommonSubstring = 1;
          } else if (i == numberOfOccurenciesOfMostCommonSubstrings) {
              numberOfSubstringsOfMostCommonSubstring++;
          }
      }

      return new int[] {
          numberOfUniqueSubstrings,
          numberOfOccurenciesOfMostCommonSubstrings,
          numberOfSubstringsOfMostCommonSubstring
      };
  }
```

later I am converting this to ArrayList and I iterate through whole list to find how many substrings and how many times these substrings are represented.

But after around 4 000 to 8 000 iterations I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` Exception (which I expect since the process of this code takes over 2GB of memory at this point (I know, storing this amount of strings in memory can take up to 2TB in edge cases)). I tried using SHA1 hash as a key, which works, but it takes way more time, there are possible collisions and I think that there might be a better way to do this, but I can't think of any "better" optimization.

Thank you for any kind of help.

**EDIT**

There is some example input => output:

```
f("abcabc", 3) => 3 2 1
f("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwqyzab", 3) => 26 1 26
f("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwqyzab", 2) => 26 2 1
```

Ive changed the code to this:

```
public static int[] countSubstringOccurence(String text, int substringLength) {
    int textLength = text.length();

    int numberOfUniqueSubstrings = 0;
    List<Integer> substrIndexes = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < (textLength - substringLength) + 1; i++) {
        boolean doesNotExists = true;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < (textLength - substringLength) + 1; j++) {
            String actualSubstr = text.substring(i, i + substringLength);
            String indexSubstr = text.substring(j, j + substringLength);
            if (actualSubstr.equals(indexSubstr)) {
                doesNotExists = false;
                substrIndexes.add(j);
            }
        }

        if (doesNotExists) {
            numberOfUniqueSubstrings++;
            substrIndexes.add(i);
        }
    }

    LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> substrCountMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (int i : substrIndexes) {
        String substr = text.substring(i, i + substringLength);

        int lastIndex = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (lastIndex != -1) {
            lastIndex = text.indexOf(substr, lastIndex);

            if (lastIndex != -1) {
                count++;
                lastIndex += substr.length();
            }
        }

        substrCountMap.put(i, count);
    }

    List<Integer> substrCountList = new ArrayList<>(substrCountMap.values());

    int numberOfOccurenciesOfMostCommonSubstrings = 0;
    int numberOfSubstringsOfMostCommonSubstring = 0;

    for (int count : substrCountList) {
        if (count > numberOfOccurenciesOfMostCommonSubstrings) {
            numberOfOccurenciesOfMostCommonSubstrings = count;
            numberOfSubstringsOfMostCommonSubstring = 1;
        } else if (count == numberOfOccurenciesOfMostCommonSubstrings) {
            numberOfSubstringsOfMostCommonSubstring++;
        }
    }

    return new int[] {
            numberOfUniqueSubstrings,
            numberOfOccurenciesOfMostCommonSubstrings,
            numberOfSubstringsOfMostCommonSubstring
    };
}
```

this code does not crash, its just really, really slow (I guess its at least O(2n^2)). Can anyone think of a faster way?

It would be great if it could fit under 1GB RAM and under 15 minutes on a CPU equal to i3-3xxx. I am done for today.

Comment: Why do you need to store the entire string you find in memory? Could you perhaps store the start and end of the substrings as integers - alongside the frequency, then pull out those substrings when needed using that data?

Comment: Have you run this through a profiler?  What has it told you?

Comment: What are your constraints, memory-, space- and time-wise? You could not store the substrings at all but instead just take the first substring, iterate over the string to find out how often it occurs, then move to the next substring, etc. You should then implement a better way to check for substring contains - do **not** get the substring and compare the result, but *try* simply see if the string *contains* the substring onwards from a given index.

Comment: What is the usecase here? Currently my only suggestion would be to save the index of the first occurence rather than saving substrings in the LinkedHashMap. But without further information its quit impossible find 'the best solution' as the actual design flaw may be in the surrounding part of your code (e.i. the part relying on this method).

Comment: Look into the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm. Use it to find all occurrences of input.substring(i, i + substringLength) for i = 0 to input.length() - substringLength. This will not be as bad as O(n²) because KMP skips hopeless sections speedily.

Comment: @Sam Ive added new code which is using only indexes, but its very slow.

Comment: @JoeC Mathematically this (before edit) code can use up to 2TB of RAM, so I dont think profiler is needed.

Comment: @luk2302 Ive added that to my edit and added new code, I will update it tomorrow, I just realised I can make it few times faster...

Comment: @tonakriz I think finding and storing indexes is indeed your best bet for saving memory. The speed will be down to your implementation of how you go about it. Take a look at this: https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/introduction-to-string-searching-algorithms/ it discusses a few common and efficient string searching algorithms. Your current implentation looks like the 'Naive' approach and is quite labour intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Run it on Java 6. Not kidding!

Java 6 substring does NOT copy the characters, but only the reference, the index and the length.

Comment: Please try to detailed answer why your recommendation is useful and how that helps.

Comment: This is an answer, as the original author asked, how to make this faster. Running it with java 6 does this. Again: Not kidding.

Answer (score -3):

just use `StrinsgTokenizer` class and extract each word.Then store each word in an array of String type of size given by the method `<object name>.countTokens();` 
then you can easily calculate the frequencies of the given word

Comment: furthermore just compare all elements and you will get the longest substring and you can calculate the frequency of each letter by extracting that word from the array

Comment: And that is faster and or more memory-efficient and or OOM-resistant? You need to provide a lot more detail on this answer.

Comment: not sure about faster but yes the problem that the person is facing will be solved